# Deploying Django Project on Pythonanywhere

Tags: python-3.x, django

I uploaded my app that worked fine on my local machine to pythonanywhere. I got it to work but instead of showing the homepage of my website it shows the "It worked, welcome to Django" page. Could someone please help me?

This is my wsgi file

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'vorakor.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

THis is my settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'website',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
]

 TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: I'll suggest you deploy the project on Heroku as it is free and more flexible than pythonanywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you transferred the complete local project? I would recommend to upload your whole project to your remote Github repository and then pull it via `git pull` from the pythonanywhere machine. Also make sure you installed every tool in your virtual environment on the remote machine.
A other thing I can think of is that, the `settings.py` file cant find your templates directoy. Make sure, that you copied it to the same place as on your local machine.